# If $abc=1,$ prove that: $\displaystyle \left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2\ge\sqrt{3}\sum_{cyc}{\sqrt[4]{4a+\frac{5}{c^2}}}$

Tags: inequality

> **Problem:**
> Let $a,b,c>0: abc=1.$ Prove that: $$\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2\ge\sqrt{3}\left(\sqrt[4]{4a+\frac{5}{c^2}}+\sqrt[4]{4b+\frac{5}{a^2}}+\sqrt[4]{4c+\frac{5}{b^2}}\right)$$

I hope someone can help me give a hint to solve hard problem. Here is my attempts:
By Minkowski inequality, it is desired to show that: $$\left(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2\ge\sqrt{3}\sqrt[4]{27\left(4(a+b+c)+5\left(\frac{1}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b^2}+\frac{1}{c^2}\right)\right)}$$
Which is not true by accounting example or I tried Minkowski inequality for unsuitable terms.

It seems relative to a lemma: For any non-negative real numbers: $(a+b+c)^5\ge81abc(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ and it did not help.

Is there better way to deal with problem? Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Anyone help me?